# SQL - Getting Name Starting with a particular letter

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a query here that doesn't work and having trouble pin pointing my mistake.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

I am trying to retrieve records with a program name starting with 'C' but my query returns zero records.

My `PROGRAM` table has an entry of a `ProgName` of `Chemistry`.

```
SELECT P.ProgNumber, ProgName, StudID, DateEnrolled
FROM PROGRAM AS P, STUDENT AS S
WHERE P.ProgNo = S.ProgNo
AND ProgName LIKE 'C%';
```

Comment: Perhaps there are no such records or there are no students associated with them.

Comment: I just double checked and there is definitely a record. thanks

Comment: What are the fields under your PROGRAM table and the STUDENT table?

Comment: if you take off the "AND XXXXXXXXX" do you get any records back?

Comment: Under PROGRAM there are ProgName and ProgNumber. STUDENT table has StudID, DateEnrolled, FirstName and LastName

Comment: If I remove AND XXXXX all the PROGRAM and StudID records are shown

Comment: and if you change (LIKE 'C%') to (= 'Chemistry') do you get your record?

Comment: Are you by chance using a case-sensitive collation, and you're searching `C%` when the actual text starts with a lower case `c`?

Comment: What is the exact name of the programs? Do they start with uppercase `C`?

Comment: If I change (LIKE 'C%') to (= 'Chemistry') I get the results for records for Chemistry

Comment: The exact name of the programs within the table are "Chemistry" and "Calculus". I've tried both 'c%' and 'C%'

Comment: which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Not sure what version it is but I am using MS Access 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
LIKE "C*"
```

MSAccess doesn't use % as the wildcard

Comment: It's working now. Thanks. I feel bad now since it was such an oversight

Comment: @GordonLinoff yea I may have a few, but they usually come from reading.. you know, that thing you should do to the comments underneath the OP...

Answer (score -1):

You need to join the different tables like this...Try this...

```
SELECT P.ProgNumber, P.ProgName, S.StudID, S.DateEnrolled
FROM PROGRAM P
JOIN STUDENT S
ON P.ProgNo = S.ProgNo
WHERE P.ProgName LIKE 'C*'; -- Asterisk because its Access not MS-SQL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    P.ProgNumber, P.ProgName, S.StudID, S.DateEnrolled
FROM 
    PROGRAM P
    JOIN STUDENT S ON S.ProgNo = P.ProgNo
WHERE 
    P.ProgName LIKE 'C%';
```

should work... you said you changed it to ='Chemistry', do you get the same result if you use lowercase c in chemistry?

Comment: I get the same results if I search for 'chemistry' with a lower case 'c'